# dynamic sql query with between condition for a date check?

Tags: sql

I have a dynamic query in my store procedure.When I have added a condition to check if date in between condition it is giving me the following error:

Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Here is my query:

```
@EffDate datetime = GETDATE()
```

inside my dynamic query:

```
set @query = @query + ' WHERE  ' + @EffDate + ' BETWEEN CONVERT(nvarchar(24), a.Eff_StartDate, 121) AND CONVERT(nvarchar(24), a.Eff_EndDate, 121)';
```

How to handle this condition?

Comment: why not write this as `'WHERE GETDATE() BETWEEN...`?

Comment: I need to pass that @EffDate externally, but default is current date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your produced @query value looks like (for example):

```
WHERE 2008-01-01 00:00:00.000 BETWEEN ...
```

You need to add quotes around your @EffDate within the query:

```
set @query = @query + ' WHERE  ''' + CONVERT(nvarchar(24), @EffDate,121) + ''' BETWEEN CONVERT(nvarchar(24), a.Eff_StartDate, 121) AND CONVERT(nvarchar(24), a.Eff_EndDate, 121)';
```

Answer (score 3):

Since you are concatenating a DateTime in your string you must convert it to a string first:

```
set @query = @query 
  + ' WHERE  ''' 
  + CONVERT(nvarchar(24),@EffDate, 121) 
  + ''' BETWEEN CONVERT(nvarchar(24), a.Eff_StartDate, 121) AND CONVERT(nvarchar(24), a.Eff_EndDate, 121)';
```

Comment: This still won't work without quotes around the literal being passed in.

Comment: As always, beware SQL Injection!  This query looks vulnerable.

Comment: @KyleHale There are quotes

Comment: You added those after my comment was posted, but fair enough : )

Answer (score 0):

In case @EffDate is not always GETDATE(), you can use a CAST:

```
CAST(@EffDate AS VARCHAR)
```

and your code should work fine. You'll have to put single quotes around it:

'WHERE @EffDate = ' + '''' + CAST(@EffDate AS VARCHAR) + '''' + .....

Answer (score 0):

```
set @query = @query + ' WHERE  ' + quotename(@EffDate,'''') + ' BETWEEN CONVERT(nvarchar(24), a.Eff_StartDate, 121) AND CONVERT(nvarchar(24), a.Eff_EndDate, 121)';
```